# How can I relate KL-divergence or other distances to the number of samples required to distinguish between two distributions?

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, information-theory

Things like KL-divergence or total variation distance tell us how far certain distributions are from each other. Say I have two distributions $p,1$ and I want to know the (smallest or expected) number of samples $m$ such that I can distinguish between $p$ and $q$ with a certain success probability. Obviously, if $p$ and $q$ are far away from each other (i.e. the TV-distance or the KL-divergence is large) then the required number of samples $m$ will be smaller. I am sure this has already been derived, would anybody have a source?

Thanks!

Comment: I think things like Neyman-Pearson and Stein's lemmas may be the ones you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

An interesting case is when $p$ and $q$ are supported on a finite set, say $[n]=\{1,\ldots,n\}.$ The paper that started research along these lines in the CS literature is Batu et al [see here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1009.5397v2). The distance used is the total variation distance.

Theorem 1. Given $\delta>0,$ and $p,q$ over $[n]$ there is a test which runs in time
$O(\epsilon^{-4} n^{2/3} \log n \log \frac{1}{\delta})$ such that if
$$TV(p,q)=|p-q|=\sum_i |p_i-q_i| \leq \max\left(\frac{\epsilon^2}{32 n^{1/3}},\frac{\epsilon}{4 n^{1/2}}\right)\quad(1),$$ then the test outputs *PASS* (i.e., that $p$ and $q$ are closer than the bound in (1)) with probability $\geq 1-\delta.$

Alternatively if $TV(p,q)> \epsilon$ the test outputs *FAIL* (i.e., that $p$ and $q$ are further away than $\epsilon$ in TV distance) with probability $\geq 1-\delta.$

The "runs in time" refers to sampling the distributions in a black box query model. Note that the probability of correct answer by the test is equal in both cases.

Comment: The link given for the paper doesn't seem correct.

Comment: @Ashok updated to arXiv link